# Can't understand the derivation of chord from Wikipedia.

Tags: trigonometry

$$crd(\theta)= \sqrt{(1-\cos\theta)^2+\sin^2\theta}=\sqrt{2-2\cos\theta}=2\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$
I'm a high school student and started using Stack today.

Comment: Could you provide the link from Wikipédia?

Comment: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_(geometry)#In_trigonometry)

Comment: Incidentally, an easier way to get to $2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}$ is to drop a perpendicular radius to the chord. This splits the chord into two paths each equal to $r\sin\frac{\theta}{2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are assuming the centre of the circle of radius $1$ to be the origin, and so the rightmost point will be $(1,0)$. Then it’s easy to verify that any point on the circle will be $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ and then just use the distance formula to get the equation you started with. Expanding the square term will lead to simplification and then use $$1-\cos \theta = 2 \sin^2 \frac{\theta}{2}$$

Comment: Thank you, now I came to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the identity
$$\sin^2(A) = \frac{1 - \cos 2A}{2}.$$
There is a problem with your formula, however. What if $\pi < \theta < 2\pi$?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the angle must lie in the interval 0<θ<=π. [Wikipedia]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_(geometry)#In_trigonometry

Comment: I am agree with Umberto P.